# Printing HTML entity codes to Screen

Tags: html, printing, entity, screen

How do you quote, type in a code line an HTML entity code word, such as a "non-breaking-space", and have the code word itself be printed to screen? Instead of the result of that word? (similar to using "& gt;" (NO space in word) for the > bracket; see, I can't even quote that word without putting in a space...)

Answer (score 0):

I believe it will be write like this &nbsp (no break space).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).